# Turn off auto-locking for specific applications

Tags: iphone

I'm just wondering if it is possible to disable auto-locking on my iPhone for specific applications? For example, I didn't want to lock screen of iPhone if LUMOback application is running in foreground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be done at the moment. The Auto-Lock setting applies to every app. The only exception to this is if an app asks iOS to prevent sleep.

You can provide feedback to Apple regarding this at the following page:

- http://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html